# Cuda Memory shared in every threads

Tags: c++, cuda

I started my adventure with CUDA today. I'm trying to share an unsigned int among all the threads. All the threads modify this value. I copied this one value to device by using cudaMemcpy. But, at the end when calculations are finished I received that this value is equal to 0.

Maybe several threads are writing to this variable at the same time?
I'm not sure if I should use any semaphores or lock this variable when a thread starts writing or what.

**EDIT:**

It's hard to say in more detail because my question is in general how to solve it. Actually I'm not writing any algorithm, only testing CUDA.

But if you wish... I created vector which contains some values (unsigned int). I tried to do something like searching values bigger than given shared value but, when value from vector is bigger, I'm adding 1 to the vector elements and save the shared value.

It looks like the this:

```
__global__ void method(unsigned int *a, unsigned int *b, long long unsigned N) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x* blockDim.x+ threadIdx.x;
    if (a[idx]>*b && idx < N) 
        *b = a[idx]+1;
}
```

As I said it's not useful code, only for testing, but I wonder how to do it...

Comment: There is insufficient detail here to really say for sure, but concurrent writes are usually considered a bad thing.

Comment: That looks like the wrong design. You want CUDA threads to work *in parallel*, so they shouldn't typically need to access one joint piece of memory.

Comment: Think about what you said and what you wrote in code. You wanted to add 1 to a shared value when the value read from the array is bigger than the shared value. What you are doing is adding 1 to the value read from the array and then assigning it to the shared value. Has every thread is writing to the same place, even if you had atomic operations every thread would just overwrite the previous value and the value you would get would be the one written by the last thread that ran. Without atomics you only get an undefined value and neither are what you wanted to do.

Comment: Nvm, what im doing. My question is in general how to use shared memory global for every threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My question is in general how to use shared memory global for every threads."

To read you don't need anything special. What you did works, faster on Fermi devices because they have a cache, slower on the others.

If you are reading the value after other threads changed it you have no way to wait for all threads to finish their operations before reading the value you want so it might not be what you expect. The only way to synchronize a value in global memory between all running threads is to use different kernels. After you change a value you want to share between all threads the kernel finishes and you launch a new one that will work with the shared value.

To make every thread write to the same memory location you must use atomic operations but keep in mind you should keep atomic operations to a minimum as this effectively serializes the execution.

To know the available atomic functions read section B.11 of the CUDA C Programming Guide [available here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf).

What you asked would be:

```
__global__ void method(unsigned int *a, unsigned int *b, long long unsigned N) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x* blockDim.x+ threadIdx.x;
    if (a[idx]>*b && idx < N) 
        //*b = a[idx]+1;
        atomicAdd(b, a[idx]+1);
}
```

Comment: ok so your solution seems to be ok. And if I want to assign value then can I use simply atomicExch(b, a[idx]+1)? Because I think it should be there...

Comment: Yeah, it's there, item B.11.1.3 in the programming guide.

Answer (score 1):

If the value is in shared memory it will only be local to every thread that runs in a single multiprocessor(i.e. per thread block) and NOT to every thread that runs for that kernel. You will definitely need to perform atomic operations (such as atomicAdd etc) if you expect each thread to be writing to the variable simultanesouly. 
Be aware though that this will serialize all simultaneous thread requests for writing to the variable.

Answer (score -1):

edit - deleted error

Although ideally you don't want to do this - unless you can be sure all the threads are going to take about the same time See [Cuda thread tutorial](http://supercomputingblog.com/cuda/cuda-tutorial-3-thread-communication/)

Comment: __ syncthreads() does not work for inter block synchronization (implied by "every thread"). He is talking about shared values in global memory, not __ shared __ memory.